# Unfortunately <MyProject> has stopped - error android

Tags: android, insert

error unfortunately ..

how to fix problem?

log

```
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.abbmobile.khoir.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:43)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.abbmobile.khoir.library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:62)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.abbmobile.khoir.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:72)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-09 16:01:46.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Don't perform network operations on the main thread. Have a look into AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Use Asynctask and do all process inside the doInBackground method.

Comment: how to create AsyncTask to myProject ?